# Updated Multiple rows ID in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to update multiple rows in Wordpress.

```
<?php
$data_type = array('%d','%d','%d','%d','%d');
$convert_datatype = implode(",",$data_type);
$list_ids = array(12,1,2,3,45); 
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE wp_testimonials SET status = %d WHERE ID IN (".$convert_datatype.") ", 1, $list_ids ) );
?>
```

Error Message

> Warning:  mysqli_query(): Empty query in wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1924

Comment: <?php
    $data_type = array('%d','%d','%d','%d','%d');

    $convert_datatype = implode(",",$data_type);

    $list_ids = array(12,1,2,3,45); 
$list_ids = implode(",",$list_ids);
     $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE wp_testimonials SET status = %d WHERE ID IN (".$convert_datatype.") ", 1, $list_ids ) );

    ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try removing IN (".$convert_datatype.") and just replacing it with 
IN $convert_datatype

As such (untested):

```
$data_type = array('%d','%d','%d','%d','%d');

$convert_datatype = implode(",",$data_type);

$list_ids = array(12,1,2,3,45); 

$wpdb->query( 
   $wpdb->prepare( 
      "UPDATE wp_testimonials SET status = %d WHERE ID IN ($convert_datatype)", 1, $list_ids
   ) 
);
```

Try this as a last resort:

```
 $wpdb->query( 
   $wpdb->prepare( 
      "UPDATE wp_testimonials SET status = %d WHERE ID IN ( %d, %d, %d, %d, %d )", 1, 12,1,2,3,45
   ) 
);
```

Comment: OK. Try now. Add () around  $convert_datatype

Comment: And if that does not work do the last resort option I added to my answer. That one should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
global $wpdb;

$list_ids = array(12,1,2,3,45);

$sql = "UPDATE wp_testimonials SET status = %d WHERE ID IN (" . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($list_ids), '%d') ) . ")";

$query = call_user_func_array(array($wpdb, 'prepare'), array_merge( array($sql), array(1), $list_ids));

$wpdb->query( $query );
```